# Setup View engine in ASP.NET MVC6 to work with AspNet.TestHost.TestServer in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, viewengine

How to setup view engine in `ASP.NET MVC 6` to work with test host created by `TestServer`. I've tried to implement the [trick](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/538cd9c19121f8d3171cbfddd5d842cbb756df3e/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FunctionalTests/MvcTestFixture.cs#L104-L126) from `MVC 6` repo:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CallMvc()
{
    var client = GetTestHttpClient();

    //call to HomeController.Index to get Home/Index.cshtml content
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    PAssert.IsTrue(() => content != null);
}

private HttpClient GetTestHttpClient(Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices = null)
{
    var applicationServices = CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider;
    var applicationEnvironment = applicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApplicationEnvironment>();
    var libraryManager = applicationServices.GetRequiredService<ILibraryManager>();
    var startupAssembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly;

    var applicationName = startupAssembly.GetName().Name;
    var library = libraryManager.GetLibraryInformation(applicationName);
    var applicationRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(library.Path);

    var hostingEnvironment = new HostingEnvironment()
    {
        WebRootPath = applicationRoot
    };

    var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();

    var startup = new Startup();

    Action<IServiceCollection> configureServicesAction = services =>
    {
        services.AddInstance(applicationEnvironment);
        services.AddInstance<IHostingEnvironment>(hostingEnvironment);

        // Inject a custom assembly provider. Overrides AddMvc() because that uses TryAdd().
        var assemblyProvider = new FixedSetAssemblyProvider();
        assemblyProvider.CandidateAssemblies.Add(startupAssembly);
        services.AddInstance<IAssemblyProvider>(assemblyProvider);

        startup.ConfigureServices(services);
    };

    Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp = _ => startup.Configure(_, hostingEnvironment, loggerFactory);
    var server = TestServer.Create(configureApp, configureServicesAction);
    var httpClient = server.CreateClient();

    return httpClient;
}
```

Startup class is just the simplest setup for MVC:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // Configure is called after ConfigureServices is called.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {       
        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

I'm getting `Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)` and internally it's not able to locate Index.cshtml view. All paths 
below are following Unit Tests library path or dnx path:

```
var applicationBasePath = _appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
var webRootPath = _env.WebRootPath;
var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

What is the way to setup view engine and environment to work from UnitTests using `TestServer`?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of defining a different environment is going to the right direction.

I have seen a quite elegant solution for this by using extension methods:

https://github.com/bartmax/TestServerMvcHelper

It is even on NuGet but I can't get it working from there. Propably you can incorporate the two classes **MvcTestApplicationEnvironment.cs** and **WebHostBuilderExtensions.cs** into your solution.

Then you can setup the TestServer by using this:

```
var builder = TestServer.CreateBuilder();
builder.UseStartup<Startup>()
   .UseEnvironment("Testing")
   .UseApplicationPath("YourMvcApplication");
var server = new TestServer(builder);
```